# Table with aligned equations inside different cells

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

How can I create tables with aligned equations in different cells? For example, see picture below. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: One way is splet last column into two, where first is right aligned and second left.

Answer (score 3):

**Version 1**:Like this (or similar)

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}
            {
                colspec        = {Q[l,m]Q[l,m]Q[l,m]},
                hline{1,Z}     = {.12em},
                hline{2}       = {.06em},
                rows           = {font=\small \bfseries},               
                row{even[2-Z]} = {gray!20}
            }       
             \SetCell[c=3]{c} Fundamentals Equations\\           
            Text 1       & Text 2  &  Text 3  \\        
            aaa     & Mathematics   & {$ax+b=c$\\$\Delta=b^2-4ac$}\\        
            ccc  & Physics & {$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$\\$Q=cm\Delta t$\\$F=ma$\\$E=mc^2$}\\  
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Version 2**: A little bit more readable and with equations numbered:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=5pt}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}
            {
                colspec        = {Q[l,m]Q[l,m]Q[l,m]},
                hline{1,Z}     = {.12em},
                hline{2}       = {.06em},
                rows           = {font=\small \bfseries},               
                row{even[2-Z]} = {gray!20}
            }       
            \SetCell[c=3]{c} Fundamentals Equations\\           
            Text 1       & Text 2  &  Text 3  \\        
            aaa     & Mathematics   & {(1)\qquad$ax+b=c$\\[1ex](2)\qquad $\Delta=b^2-4ac$}\\        
            ccc  & Physics & {(3)\qquad $F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$\\[1ex](4)\qquad $Q=cm\Delta t$\\[1ex](5)\qquad $F=ma$\\[1ex](6)\qquad $E=mc^2$}\\  
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Raffaelle Santoro, I suggest using (p.47 doc tabularray)
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}(\arabic{mycnta})\qquad}, to number equations.

Comment: @pascal974 Suggestion for alex. Thanks.

Comment: @pascal974 In any case I installed the counter You suggested. It works very well! Thanks. For a long list is very useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is great!

Comment: @alex The rule of this site is: I like the answer, I accept the answer.